# *args returns a list containing only those arguments that are even

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python and in an exercise I need to write a function that takes an arbitrary number of arguments and returns a list containing only those arguments that are even.

My code is wrong I know: (But what is wrong with this code ?)

```
def myfunc(*args):
    for n in args:
        if n%2 == 0:
            return list(args)
myfunc(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

Comment: Create a list like `output = []` then append `n` into it if `n` is even: `output.append(n)`. Then return `output` at the end of `myfunc`.

Comment: All you are doing is returning *all* the arguments if *any* argument is even.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do a list-comprehension which picks elements from `args` that matches our selection criteria:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    return [n for n in args if n%2 == 0]

print(myfunc(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

This also could be helpful, however, the previous comment looks more advanced:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    lista = []
    for i in list(args):
        if not i % 2:
            lista.append(i)
    return lista
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick evens

```
def myfunc(*args):
    abc = []
    for n in args:
        if n%2==0:
            abc.append(n) 
    return abc
```

Comment: This is (almost) exactly the same code as Mahyar Khatiri's answer from January. If you really thing the few small changes you've made are important, please explain them with either comments in the code, or extra text.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def myfunc(*args):
    mylist = []
    for x in list(args):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            mylist.remove(x)
    return mylist
```

Comment: Hi Nahean!, and welcome to SE! To better help the asker and future readers, along with working code, please include what the problem was and how you fixed it. Also, please read over formatting guidelines to learn how to format code properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfunc(*args):
    even=[]
    for n in args:
        if n %2==0:
            even.append(n)
        else:
            pass
        
    return even
myfunc(1,2,3,4,8,9)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfunc(*args):
    #solution 1
    # Create an empty list
    mylist = []
    for number in args:
        if number %2 == 0:
            mylist.append(number)
        else:
            pass
    # return the list
    return mylist
    
    #solution 2
    # Uses a list comprehension that includes the logic to find all evens and the list comprehension returns a list of those values
    # return [n for n in args if n%2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an empty list to contain the even numbers. Also convert your arguments to a list. Then append the even numbers to the newly created list.

```
def myfunc(*args):
new_list = []
for num in list(args):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        new_list.append(num)
else:
    pass
return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfunc(*args):
    return [x for x in args if not x&1]
```

Comment: Hi Pham, thanks for the contribution. However please include an explanation with your answer. This is a community for people to learn and just answering with a code snippet that has no explanation of what or how it works is not helpful for learning.

Answer (score -1):

```
def myfunc(*args):
    x=[]
    for i in list(args):
        if i%2==0:
            x.append(i)
    return x
```

Comment: Hi naruto, and welcome to SE! To better help the asker and future readers, along with working code, please include what the problem was and how you fixed it. Also, please read over [formatting guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to format code properly.